# Double const declaration

Tags: c++, function, constants

I often see the following function declaration:

```
some_func(const unsigned char * const buffer)
{

}
```

Any idea why the const is repeated before the pointer name?

Thanks.

Comment: It should be `const unsigned char* const`

Comment: iirc unsigned char const * const also is valid

Comment: No, you don't see such declarations "often". The declaration is, in fact, invalid and thus makes no sense. Please, be more careful when posting code with your questions.

Comment: Reading the declaration from right to left will give you a better understanding.  `const unsigned char * const` is a constant pointer (`*const`) to an constant unsigned char (`const unsigned char`).

Comment: Sorry, corrected to right syntax.

The right to left reading advice is very useful, thanks!
(I actually remembered studying something about the compiler parsing in RTL fashion during CS courses :) )

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The first `const` says that the data pointed to is constant and may not be changed whereas the second `const` says that the pointer itself may not be changed:

```
char my_char = 'z';
const char* a = &my_char;
char* const b = &my_char;
const char* const c = &my_char;

a = &other_char; //fine
*a = 'c'; //error
b = &other_char; //error
*b = 'c'; //fine
c = &other_char; //error
*c = 'c'; //error
```

Comment: +1 But might I suggest adding examples demonstrating that const pointers may not be reassigned.  (i.e., `char* const x = NULL; x = &some_char;`)

Comment: @Eric I believe I already included that `b = &other_char; //error`

Comment: I believe I need to pay more attention :) My apologies

Answer (score 10):

type declarations should(?) be read RTL.  `const` modifies the thing on its left, but the rule is complicated by the fact that you can write both `const T` and `T const` (they mean the same thing).

- `T * const` is a *constant pointer to mutable T*
- `T & const` would be *constant reference to mutable T*, except references are constant by definition
- `T const *` is a *mutable pointer to constant T*
- `T const &` is a *reference to constant T*
- `T const * const` is *constant pointer to constant T*

Comment: Thanks, the RTL reading advice is useful for such feature cases.

Answer (score 3):

It's a constant pointer to a constant unsigned char. You can't change the pointer nor the thing it points to.

Answer (score 3):

In a declaration like `const  * const T`, the first `const` (before the `*`) means that what the pointer points *at* is `const` (i.e. it's a pointer to a `const T`). The `const` after the `*` means that the pointer *itself* is `const` (i.e. can't be modified to point at anything else).

You can read the declaration from the object being declared outward, so `const unsigned char * const buffer` is read as: "buffer is a const pointer to a const unsigned char" (this is why `const` should always being placed *after* what it modifies--with it before, you have to rearrange things to make the sentence--with it declared as `unsigned char const * const buffer`, translation to English is simple and straighforward (or perhaps "straightbackward", since you actually read from right to left in this case).

Answer (score 2):

assuming const unsigned char * const

Everyone is correct that its a const pointer to a const unsigned char.

C++ types read mostly *right to left* unless there are any modifiers on the far left then these read left to right.

Answer (score 1):

This makes it a const pointer to a const value, rather than a mutable pointer to a const value or a const pointer to a mutable value.

Answer (score 1):

`const * unsigned char const buffer` means that you cannot modify the pointer `buffer` nor the memory that `buffer` points to.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of articles to help you understand const correctness in C++:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness)
- [Possibility.com](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/const.html)