# How do I check if a const char*'s value is defined?

Tags: c++, c

My application reads settings from a conf file first, and then those options can be overwritten from the cli arguments. After it loads the settings from the conf, I need to check if the require values are set but I'm stuck at making it check the variables.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

const char* test;

if (test != NULL)
   std::cout << test << "\n";
else
   std::cout << "no value set\n";

return 0;
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What's the concrete problem? What happens? What *should* happen? (You didn't initialize `test`.)

Comment: re-tagged to c as well. Even though there are C++-specific stuff here (only the streams, really), the question (and the answer) is C-oriented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't initialize `test`. If you want it to be `NULL` initially, you have to set it:

```
const char* test = NULL;
```

Comment: But if I initialize it as NULL, doesn't that mean I won't be able to change its value later (because it's const char*)?

Comment: @code: No, you have a pointer to `const char` here. Even if it were a `const` pointer (`const char* const`) you can only set its value by initializing it and couldn't modify it later on anyway.

Comment: It's `const char*`, not `char* const`. A const pointer is not the same as a pointer to const.

Comment: @codefrog: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const) should clear things up regarding `const` and pointers.

Comment: @codefrog - see this previous question for background on your question here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156305/double-const-declaration

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ do not initialize pointers to NULL automatically.
If you do not assign it a value, it still has a value, it is just an unknown, indeterminate value.  It could be NULL, it could be something else.

In your sample code, `test` has a value, but it is unknown.
So your if-statement might or might not be true.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative that is more idiomatic for C++, you could use a string and check whether it's empty after your init completes:

```
#include <string>

std::string test;   // default constructor produces an empty string

// do the config load

if (test.empty())
{
  // config error
}
```

Note that if the data semantics here include an empty value being legitimate, this alternative is not viable.

Comment: A string is not in general the same thing as an optional string. Sometimes "set to empty" doesn't mean the same thing as "unset", so it's more about the data model than it is about idiom.

Comment: @Steve - that's true - if the data semantics here include an empty value being legitimate, this alternative is not viable.

Comment: In that case, with that said, `string` is indeed more idiomatic than `char*` to contain a string in C++. Questioner: use it where possible!

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

You cannot check a "defined" state in C/C++ if you haven't "defined" that state yourself. Don't leave initialization up to your compiler implementation if you are doing something like this.

Initialize your pointer to NULL.