# Using const keyword in c

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, constants, declaration

I have been looking at a source code, and i came across this code

```
    static char const *const delimit_method_string[] =
    {
        "none", "prepend", "separate", NULL
    };
```

I thought I knew the meaning of `const` keyword in the **C** language but after seeing this syntax I am confused as I can't decode the meaning of the syntax, so I wanted to know the meaning of using `const` like this I searched internet I saw some questions like this in stackoverflow that are,

1. [Meaning of two const in C/C++ signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972943/meaning-of-two-const-in-c-c-signature)
2. [Double const declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156305/double-const-declaration)

But still I don't understand what's the meaning of the syntax in that code snippet, may be that because I am not good enough with fundamentals of **C** but I really like to improve it.

So I wrote some code to know how that syntax works, this is what I tried:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        char a = 'A';
        char b = 'B';
        char const * const ptr = &a;

        ptr = &b;

        printf("a is %c\n", *ptr);
        printf("a is %c", a);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

I got this output, that somewhat I expected.

```
$ gcc test.c
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:9:13: error: assignment of read-only variable 'ptr'
    9 |         ptr = &b;
      |  

                    ^
```

I changed the code and tested again,

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        char a = 'A';
        char b = 'B';
        char const const *ptr = &a;
    
        ptr = &b;

        printf("a is %c\n", *ptr);
        printf("a is %c", a);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

this time the output is not what I expected,

```
$ ./a.exe
a is B
a is A
```

I really appreciate if someone can explain what is the correct way of using `const` in **C** and also how the syntax in first code snippet works.

Comment: What did you expect for the second snippet?

Comment: @tstanisl i thought i will get an error like before but i didn't get any

Comment: I don't find my 2 cents sufficient for an answer, but I always try to read the declaration backwards: so `static char const *const delimit_method_string`: `delimit_method_string` is a `const` pointer `*` which points to a `const` ((unmodifyable) `char`, which is `static`. This helps me understand it.

Comment: @DavidTóth yeah that makes sense, Thanks for the trick:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declaration

```
static char const *const delimit_method_string[] =
{
  "none", "prepend", "separate", NULL
};
```

declares an array with the name `delimit_method_string` of pointers to string literals.

In C opposite to C++ string literals have types of non-constant character arrays. Nevertheless you may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior. So it is better to declare pointers to string literals the following way as for example

```
const char *s = "Hello";
```

So you could declare the above array like

```
static char const * delimit_method_string[] =
{
  "none", "prepend", "separate", NULL
};
```

But the programmer who declared this array also wanted to declare at as a constant array. That is he wanted that its elements can not be changed.

For the declaration above you can write for example

```
delimit_method_string[0] = "all";
```

To prevent such a changing elements of the array must be constant.  To do this you need to write

```
static char const * const delimit_method_string[] =
{
  "none", "prepend", "separate", NULL
};
```

Now the elements of the array that have the pointer type `const char *` are constant due to the second qualifier const.

Tom make it more clear consider the following declarations.

```
char *p;
```

This declaration declares a non-constant pointer to a non-constant object of the type `char`.

```
const char *p;
```

This declaration declares a non-constant pointer to a constant object of the type `char`.

```
const char * const p;
```

This declaration declares a constant pointer to a constant object of the type `char`.

The last declaration may be rewritten like

```
const char ( * const p );
```

As for this your declaraion

```
char const const *ptr = &a;
```

then on of the two qualifiers `const` is redundant because the both refer to the type specifier `char`.

Comment: Good explanation! You might add that `static`, `const` and `char` can appear in any order before the `*` with the same meaning.  `static const char *p` and `static char const *p` are equivalent, as well as `char const static *p`, which is quite confusing :)

Answer (score 3):

```
char const const *ptr = &a;
```

This double `const` does not have any special meaning as both are on the same side of the `*`. Additional `const` qualifiers are ignored by the compiler. You can write `char const const const const const*ptr = &a;` It is the same as char const  *ptr = &a; which means:

```
pointer to constant character
```

If we change it to

```
char const * const ptr = &a;
```

It will mean:

```
constant pointer to constant char
```

Your snippet will stop to compile: https://godbolt.org/z/sM9qnv8fq

examples:

- `const int *ptr;` - pointer to constant integer
- `int * const ptr;` - constant pointer to integer
- `const int * const ptr;` - constant pointer to constant integer

Your first example `static char const *const delimit_method_string[]` declares:

```
static array of constant pointers to constant character
```

BTW I personally prefer to have the first const before the type ie:

> `static const volatile char *const delimit_method_string[]`
>
> `const char *p`